# codeigniter 1 database per client

Tags: database, codeigniter

Trying to transform one app which serves one client for several customers where each has its own database.

I have a fully working app with one database in CodeIgniter with login, register user, logout...

Now I want to have login page and according to user open the app with matching database.

login database and set client database until he logs out.

login database:id, login, password, database

All clients database are the same but it will be easier to set on several servers and keep data separated.

I don't expect a large number of clients but the entire app is the same for all expect the database content. Any ideas? I have searched a lot and couldn't find any tutorial on this.

Comment: Do you want to create a database on the fly for subdomains? each client having something like `client1.mydomain.com`? Are you using shared hosting? or are you on your own server? which database are you using? This is a very broad question!

Comment: No subdomain Just web page with link to login. Each client logs in and has access to his data. I have server hosting like hostgator i set my App on cpanel. My dB was mysql when i set on-line i had to chance to mariadb. Well all is working on line for single client. Só now i’m trying to have base code same for all, database  same for all only dB name changes. If i wanted subdomains i had just to tell each client a diferent address and it Will work but to develop further app i Need app only in one place. I believe separated dB is beter due to sensitive information.